# Opening from favourites bar opens in a different window / icon

Tags: unity, firefox

I followed this guide to install firefox developer edition https://medium.com/@js_debugger/how-to-install-firefox-developer-edition-on-ubuntu-1c7f5f2b6883 it is all installed and working fine but I have added it to my favourites and instead of opening in the icon in favourites it opens in a new icon, I want it to just open in the same icon like all my other favourites. Any ideas?

[picture showing new icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDSA0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the left Firefox icon, then select "Remove from favorites". Then right-click the rightmost icon of your running firefox, and select "Add to favourites". You can then drag that icon to the left where the old icon was.

This way, you replace the icon of the standard version that comes with Ubuntu with your custom Firefox developper edition that you installed.

If you wish, you could remove the default firefox with the command `sudo apt remove firefox`.

Comment: it doesn't have the add to favourites option, I can only get it by looking at all the applications and right clicking from there

Comment: You are not using the standard Ubuntu desktop? It is actually not clear what desktop environment you are using.